# How TokenURI function was called in opensea

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

How OpenSea call the tokenURI function ?
I want to use the keyword (msg.sender) but it didn't work ideally.
Or maybe I have some error in my code ?

```
mapping(address=>bool) addr_bool;

function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

       if(addr_bool[msg.sender] == true) {
            return URI_1;
            // addr_bool[msg.sender] is true;
        }
          else {
            return URI_2;
        }
         

        if (bytes(base).length == 0) {
            return _tokenURI;
        }
        if (bytes(_tokenURI).length > 0) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(base, _tokenURI));
        }

        return
            string(abi.encodePacked(base, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension));
    }
```

I expect to see , if data in mapping is true. In OpenSea, it will show URI_1, if not it will show URI_2

Comment: i don't know how opensea works internally so msg.sender may not really be the actual sender, couldn't find anything on their docs either

Comment: Thanks. I can't find anything about it too.

Comment: Sorry @SpaceNinja, you can ping me if you are stuck with something else in the future